# Springboot ElasticSearch Configuration Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I try to write config for elasticsearchclient but i keep getting an error like this :

---

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

```
co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientOptions.initialOptions(RestClientOptions.java:179)
```

The following method did not exist:

```
org.elasticsearch.client.RequestOptions$Builder.addHeader(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/elasticsearch/client/RequestOptions$Builder;
```

The method's class, org.elasticsearch.client.RequestOptions$Builder, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/C:/Users/UtkuUslusoy/.m2/repository/org/elasticsearch/client/elasticsearch-rest-client/6.8.3/elasticsearch-rest-client-6.8.3.jar!/org/elasticsearch/client/RequestOptions$Builder.class
```

It was loaded from the following location:

```
file:/C:/Users/UtkuUslusoy/.m2/repository/org/elasticsearch/client/elasticsearch-rest-client/6.8.3/elasticsearch-rest-client-6.8.3.jar
```

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.elasticsearch.client.RequestOptions$Builder

```java
@Configuration
public class ElasticsearchConfiguration {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ElasticsearchConfiguration.class);

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchClient elasticsearchClient(
            @Value(value = "${com.**.**.core.configuration.**.mappingFile}") String mappingFile,
            @Value(value = "${com.**.**.core.configuration.**.indexName}") String indexName,
            @Value(value = "${com.**.**.core.configuration.**.hostName}") String hostName,
            @Value(value = "${com.**.**.core.configuration.**.port}") Integer port) throws IOException {

        final RestClient restClient = RestClient
                .builder(new HttpHost(hostName, port))
                .build();

        final ElasticsearchTransport transport = new RestClientTransport(restClient, new JacksonJsonpMapper());

        final ElasticsearchClient client = new ElasticsearchClient(transport);

        final InputStream stream = new ClassPathResource(mappingFile).getInputStream();

        final CreateIndexRequest request = new CreateIndexRequest.Builder().index(indexName).withJson(stream).build();

        try { client.indices().create(request); } catch (Throwable exception) { /* Intentionally left blank */ }

        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) logger.debug("Elasticsearch initialization complete");

        return client;
    }
}
```

Springboot Version :2.2.0.RELEASE

pom.xml:

```xml
<dependencies>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/co.elastic.clients/elasticsearch-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>co.elastic.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-java</artifactId>
        <version>7.17.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Needed only if you use the spring-boot Maven plugin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.json-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.integration/spring-integration-amqp -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-amqp</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.**.**</groupId>
        <artifactId>aml-core</artifactId>
        <version>${**.aml.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <elasticsearch-version>7.17.2</elasticsearch-version>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.17.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch.client/transport -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
            <version>7.17.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Add these to your pom.